# C++ map is not constructed

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have a struct as follows;

```
struct LIBRARY_EXPORT gpuprogram_t {
public:
    GLuint gpuprogram_handle;
    gpuprogram_t();
    ~gpuprogram_t();
    void attach_shader(GLuint shader_handle, GLuint shader_type);
    void link_program();
    void use_program();
    void add_attribute(const std::string& attribute);
    void add_uniform(const std::string& uniform);

    GLuint operator[](const std::string& attribute);
    GLuint operator()(const std::string& uniform);
private:
    std::map<GLuint, GLuint> shaders;
    std::map<std::string, GLuint> attribute_list;
    std::map<std::string, GLuint> uniform_list;
};
```

I am using this to manage some OpenGL. I implemented these things in its .cpp file. In my implementation of attach_shader there is a part;

```
if (shaders.find(shader_type) == shaders.end()) {
    // No shader of this type is attached before
    shaders.insert(std::pair<GLuint, GLuint>(shader_type, shader_handle));
    ...
}
```

Also my constructor is like this;

```
gpuprogram_t::gpuprogram_t() {
    gpuprogram_handle = glCreateProgram();
}
```

If you want to build MCVE yourself, you can leave other parts of the impementation empty and use it like;

```
gpuprogram_t gp;
gp.attach_shader(shader_handle, shader_type)
```

Here you don't have to have GLuints of OpenGL, you can change them to normal int.
This part gives me segmentation fault everytime. I don't know what is wrong with the map shaders. I am not initializing it at the constructor. I kept it as it is in the header file so that it would be initialized with default constructor. Then I will fill it through attach_shader. Later when program object gets out of scope, all will be deleted. But clearly I am doing something wrong. shaders map is probably always garbage, leading to segmentation faults everytime. What is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe the whole object of type `LIBRARY_EXPORT` is not constructed? Are you are using a pointer to access this object? You could check whether it is valid.

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE](/help/mcve)?

Comment: LIBRARY_EXPORT is just macro for __decl DLL import exports and defined to be nothing in the non-windows environments and I am still getting seg faults on Linux. Also I am not accessing it through a pointer.

Comment: If I were you, I use shaders[shader_type] = shader_handle

Comment: @mustafagonul I tried every way to insert into a map I can find.

Comment: And if you want to create a pair, you can use make_pair function.

Comment: Memory errors in completely unrelated code can cause things like this. Run your program under valgrind to see if it reports anything.

Comment: Or make a tiny project with just a few header files and this class, and see if it still crashes. Work your way down until you have just a single map if you have to.

Comment: You don't even need the `if (shaders.find(shader_type)...` check.  The `insert` will not overwrite an existing entry.

Comment: @meguli You should be checking if your instance of `gpuprogram_t` is valid.  If the object is not valid, then no members inside of it are valid.

Comment: Are you declaring your `gpuprogram_t` as a static somewhere?

Comment: gpuprogram is a global variable declared outside all scope. And I am pretty much sure that object itself is created because it lets me call the function attach_shader. But inside attach_shader, working with this map called shaders is not working. It is a private member and I don't do anything with that map on the constructor. Shouldn't it be initialized empty with a default constructor at object creation if I leave it out of constructor?

Comment: @meguli In that small example, remove the call to `glCreateProgram` in the constructor.  Do you still see a crash?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Nope, it is still same.

Comment: @meguli  Cannot duplicate:  http://ideone.com/9lAVXP

Comment: The reason I asked if it was a static is because the behaviour you describe sounds a lot like the _static initialisation order fiasco_.  If you have declared your static in one place and are calling it from the constructor of a static object somewhere else, then you may be a victim.

Comment: @meguli "*And I am pretty much sure that object itself is created because it lets me call the function attach_shader.*"  --  That does not prove if the object is fully created.  Also, are there any side-effects of calling `glCreateProgram` before `main` starts?  That is what is happening when you construct the object, since it is a global variable.

Comment: @meguli I did mean `gpuprogram_t`. I did not see, that the real name of the class is behind the macro. I think that the whole object is not constructed when you call the method. Just like written by paddy and PaulMcKenzie. Another thing: You cannot call a function of *OpenGL* without creating an context and initilizing *GLEW*, or whatever you are using to get access to the functions. This mean that it is an error to construct `gpuprogram_t` statically while the constructor is calling an OpenGL-function like `glCreateProgram`.

Comment: @JojOatXGME Yes, the problem was that I was creating gpuprogram before OpenGL context. Slipped from my eyes and cost me many hours.